# LDAP OpenQuery returns only one column ADsPath

Tags: sql-server, active-directory, linked-server, openquery

I have added my Domain Controller as a linked server to SQL Server in order to pull some data from active directory and populate my tables with it. After that, I have executed an OpenQuery to get the users list in my domain

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(ADSI, 'SELECT * FROM ''LDAP://OU=SmallOU, DC=MyDOMAIN,DC=xx,DC=xx'' WHERE objectClass=''User'' ')
```

I have performed the query against a small OU since performing the query against the whole directory returned errors because of number of rows limitation

Surprisingly, the query returns only one column "`ADsPath`", whereas I expected to get `sAMAccount`, `Title`, `Last Name`, .... ,etc.

[image]

I want to get all the users data, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider will not try to find out which attributes to retrieve, if you use the asterisk with the SQL syntax.  Instead of `SELECT *` you must specify the attributes you want like `SELECT sAMAccountName, sn, givenName`.

Comment: Thank you that solved my problem, although I am astonished that it works this way!